# How to create dynamic stored procedure in SQL Anywhere?

Tags: database, procedure

I'm having an issue with creating dynamic sql statement in SQL Anywhere.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pplAnalysis
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000)

  SELECT @Sql = "select * from cds.ppl"

  EXECUTE(@Sql)

END
```

When I execute this procedure, I get an `Column 'select * from cds.ppl' not found` error.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whatever you write after the from has to be an object in the database, a table or a view, and table/view names cannot have a dot in between. What is cds.ppl?

Answer (score 2):

The issue had to do with syntax and the `RESULT` clause; after adding semicolons, `RESULT` clause, and used `SET` to initialize the Sql variable, here is what worked (tested in SQL Anywhere Network Server Version 12.0.1):

```
drop proc pplAnalysis;

CREATE PROCEDURE pplAnalysis()
RESULT (cnot CHAR(5), cnull CHAR(5), vnot VARCHAR(5), vnull VARCHAR(5), explanation VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000);

  SET @Sql = 'select cnot, cnull, vnot, vnull, explanation from dbo.spaces';

  EXECUTE ( @Sql );

END;
```

`spaces` is a table in the `dbo` schema and those columns are the same type specified in `RESULT`

Tested these two ways to execute the procedure and both returned result:

```
call pplAnalysis();

cnot  cnull vnot  vnull explanation                                        
----- ----- ----- ----- -------------------------------------------------- 
Execution time: 0.027 seconds
Procedure completed
```

or

```
exec pplAnalysis;

cnot  cnull vnot  vnull explanation                                        
----- ----- ----- ----- -------------------------------------------------- 
Execution time: 0.018 seconds
```

For more details:

[Returning result sets from procedures](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbusage_en11/ptrrmr.html)

[Create procedure statement](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/create-procedure-user-defined-statement.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try first saving the result of the query in a temporal table, and then do a `SELECT` from the temporal table:

```
SELECT @Sql = "select into #temp * from cds.ppl"

EXECUTE(@Sql)

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes.

```
SELECT @Sql = 'select * from cds.ppl'
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it seems like it doesn't like it with single quote either.

Comment: @user1344736 IF cds is your table and ppl a column in that table then you can do: select ppl from cds or select * from cds. What you CANNOT DO is: select * from cds.ppl

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I have edited my answer.

Regarding the `EXECUTE ( string-expression )` statement, yes you have to use single quotes instead of double quotes for the string expression. [This](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/execute-tsql-statement.html) page mentions:

> It lets you execute dynamically prepared statements, such as
>   statements that are constructed using the parameters passed in to a
>   procedure. Literal strings in the statement must be enclosed in single
>   quotes, and the statement must be on a single line.

Which will eliminate the column not found error but the procedure will return this other error:

```
Result set not permitted in '<batch statement>'
```

Same error returned when trying to execute this statement alone:

```
execute ('select * from sysusers')
```

With [probable cause](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/saerrors/errm946.html):

> You attempted to execute a SELECT statement in a context where a
>   result set is not permitted.

See my most recent answer for the solution.

And regarding schemas, here's how to refer to objects:

> It is always good practice to refer to database objects by a schema
>   name and the object name, separated by a period (.). For a complete example, to SELECT records from the Employee table in the HumanResources schema of the current database would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee
```

> To reference an object located in a remote database, the fully
>   qualified object name includes the server name and the database name.
>   For example, to SELECT records from the Employee table in the
>   HumanResources schema in the AdventureWorks database on MyServer would
>   look like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyServer.AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Employee
```

I tested that in SQL Anywhere 12 and it works the same. And even though I was not familiar with schemas, what I'm suggesting you below is actually using schemas, dbowner would be the schema name:

1) `select * from dbname.dbowner.tablename`

2) `select * from dbowner.tablename`

3) `select * from dbname..tablename` (assumes table exists in the `dbo` schema)

Bottom line.... In your select statement `cds.ppl` has to be a table named `ppl` created in the `cds` schema.

Or if `cds` is your database name and `ppl` your table name created in the `dbo` schema, you are missing a dot:

```
select * from cds..ppl
```

Comment: Apparently you're not familiar with [schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=SQL.100).aspx).

Comment: @GSerg I'm honest, I'm not familiar with schemas. However, the fact that so far, user1344736 has been mute about what cds.ppl is even after asking him, and not even mentioning what version of SQL Anywhere he is using, makes your down vote and assumption abusive. Your link is pointing to a Microsoft SQL Server 2005, 2008 related page, when user1344736 said is using SQL Anywhere.

Comment: @GSerg And you thought it had to do with those quotes? Be honest and down vote your own answer too, because clearly the use of apostrophes instead of quotes did not resolve the issue. Read user1344736 comment to your answer again.

Comment: Downvoting one's own answer is rather pointless. I'd either delete the answer or improve it. However, I'm not sure exactly how "it doesn't like it with single quote either," and, given the lack of details in this statement, not exactly keen to come up with clarifying questions.

Comment: As for your assumption, I see it as wrong because the error is `Column 'select * from cds.ppl' not found`. If you were right, it would complain about `cds.ppl`, not the whole expression being interpreted as a column name (because in SQL single quotes are for strings, and double quotes are *generally* for identifiers, and SQL Anywhere [adheres to that](http://books.google.ru/books?id=Vf_EgfsFw-8C&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%22SQL+Anywhere%22+double+quotes&source=bl&ots=pukkF6OLfW&sig=BcRYDOvm-ZGR-FBjPDJJV4nvOAQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=cB2RT_WyMs7t-gaL45T_Aw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&f=false).).