# Manage a for loop in sql related to the change in c#? there are more than 4 modifier that we need to add to our list

Tags: c#, sql, for-loop

I have C# and SQL code that work together. Issue was I need to add more than 4 modifier in my list but it was not possible, so I change the c# code and related to that I need to change my SQL code. I do not know how may I put for loop in SQL. Help me please.

I have a table that I need to add "n" modifier on it.

Here is the c# code that I changed:

```
int n = updatedStudy.Modifiers.Count;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    string @pu_examCodeModifier = "@pu_examCodeModifier" + i;
    sqlParm.Add(@pu_examCodeModifier, updatedStudy.Modifiers[i - 1].Key, SQLEnumerations.SQLDataTypes.UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 0);
}
```

and here is SQL code that I need to change :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [v0000].[apUpdateOrder] (
    @pu_fillerOrderKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @pu_examCodeKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @pu_examCodeModifier1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL ,
    @pu_examCodeModifier2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
    @pu_examCodeModifier3 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
    @pu_examCodeModifier4 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
    @ps_fillerOrderStatusCd VARCHAR(1),
    @ps_priorityCd VARCHAR(10),
    @pb_exam_stat_flag BIT)
AS
BEGIN
    --exam code modifiers
    IF (@pb_updateStudyModifiers IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM dbo.mapProcedureStepExamCodeModifier 
        WHERE procedureStepKey = @lu_procedureStepKey

        IF (@pu_examCodeModifier1 IS NOT NULL)
           INSERT INTO dbo.mapProcedureStepExamCodeModifier (procedureStepKey, examCodeModifierKey)
           VALUES (@lu_procedureStepKey, @pu_examCodeModifier1)

        IF (@pu_examCodeModifier2 IS NOT NULL)
           INSERT INTO dbo.mapProcedureStepExamCodeModifier (procedureStepKey, examCodeModifierKey)
           VALUES (@lu_procedureStepKey, @pu_examCodeModifier2)

        IF (@pu_examCodeModifier3 IS NOT NULL)
           INSERT INTO dbo.mapProcedureStepExamCodeModifier (procedureStepKey, examCodeModifierKey)
           VALUES (@lu_procedureStepKey, @pu_examCodeModifier3)

        IF (@pu_examCodeModifier4 IS NOT NULL)
           INSERT INTO dbo.mapProcedureStepExamCodeModifier (procedureStepKey, examCodeModifierKey)
           VALUES (@lu_procedureStepKey, @pu_examCodeModifier4)   
   END
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: do you need [table valued parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)?

Comment: I need to change my parameter type I think, not sure. I need to put all 4 @pu_examCodeModifier to one comma separated value list. in this case I can add more than 4

Answer (score 0):

Putting loops onto the DB side is generally adviseable. Putting this kind of work onto the Client Side is only slower and prone to race conditions.

As I read it, you want to react on the previous values of that row when deleting it. There are several ways to go about this:

**Delete Trigger**. Especially if this is more then a one time re-stucturing and the table will stay around, I would go for [DML triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers). It is still part of the Original DML Orders Transaction and Lockout, so it is has little danger of race conditions.

**OUTPUT Syntax**. There is often a need to get data from rows you just inserted, Updated or Deleted. The [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) is there for you. Once again, this is part of the Original DML's Transaction. Plus it can access auto values that were literally just created (like Primary Keys).

The core **Loop** of SQL is the more generic [while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql). The trick is to make a Stored Procedure that takes a [Table Valued Paramter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) basically an array, where you hand in stuff like Primary. Or extracts the Primary keys into a local variable itself.

If you need a index or any other temporary variable, just make one yourself. That is what [DECLARE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql) is there for.

One thing about loop modification worth considering is the transactions and lockouts. By default every single DML statemetn will be wrapped into a seperate Transaction and aquire seperate lockout. That can add a ton of overhead. So it can be beneficial to do the transaction and lock creation yourself - just keep in mind to lock all tables you may need instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the example you have provided, there are a couple of problems in there, like where *@pb_updateStudyModifiers* and *@lu_procedureStepKey* come from.

Regarding the specific question of how to loop in SQL, the answer is:

-If you already know the values, and they are numeric, use a while:

```
DECLARE @ID INT = 0

WHILE @ID < 3
BEGIN
    SELECT @ID = @ID + 1
    SELECT 'The current ID is: ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR)
END
```

-If you need to loop through other value types, you will need an auxiliary table and a CURSOR. This is an example of how to loop through a table ( doing the same thing I did above using just the INT variable ):

```
DECLARE @EXAMPLE_IDS TABLE (
    ID INT
)
-- POPULATE THE EXAMPLE TABLE
INSERT INTO @EXAMPLE_IDS VALUES ( 1 )
INSERT INTO @EXAMPLE_IDS VALUES ( 2 )
INSERT INTO @EXAMPLE_IDS VALUES ( 3 )


DECLARE EXAMPLE_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM @EXAMPLE_IDS

DECLARE @CURRENT_ID INT

OPEN EXAMPLE_CURSOR

-- GET FIRST ELEMENT
FETCH NEXT FROM EXAMPLE_CURSOR INTO @CURRENT_ID

-- THIS IS YOUR LOOP
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- DO YOUR STUFF HERE 
    SELECT 'The current ID is: ' + CAST(@CURRENT_ID AS VARCHAR)
    -- GET NEXT ID
    FETCH NEXT FROM EXAMPLE_CURSOR INTO @CURRENT_ID
END

CLOSE EXAMPLE_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE EXAMPLE_CURSOR
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I need to pass multiple values to single comma separated data parameter in stored procedure. actually I need to put all modifiers in one comma separated data type in some way cause I need to have a no limitation space for my modifier to add more than 4 or less. I may not need for or while loop, I am not sure

Comment: No worries. If you need to separate the comma-separated parameter, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26611977/9518363) could be helpful to you.
If you need to loop through the resulting table, just use CURSOR.